# Mysql slow query log not honoring long_query_time variable, logs really quick queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm running mysql 5.5 and am debugging a performance issue. I have enabled mysql slow logging. These are my relevant settings in my.cnf:

```
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Mysql is indeed creating and writing to a slow query log. However, it logging lots of queries that run much, much quicker than specified by the long_query_time parameter.

Here are a couple examples of that:

```
# Query_time: 0.000142  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1 
# Query_time: 0.000081  Lock_time: 0.000024 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 0.000116  Lock_time: 0.000034 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
```

There are actually no instances of queries that have query or lock times that, together, add up to anything greater than 0.1. From my reading of what the long_query_time parameter is supposed to do, I would not expect to find those queries in the slow query log.

Comment: This is a question about DBMS configuration, not programming, so it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ah, good call. Sorry if I posted this to the wrong SE site. Happy to move it there if it's not too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing the my.cnf does not apply the changes to the running instance. You must restart the MySQL Service for my.cnf to take effect.

Alternatively, you can use `SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 10` to apply the equivalent change in the currently running instance.

My habit is to do **both**: edit my.cnf so that the next time I restart MySQL Service, it takes effect, and then I also use `SET GLOBAL` to apply the same changes to the running instance. Understand that not every MySQL server variable can be changed dynamically like that.

Note also that only *new* client connections will get that global value. Existing client connections will continue to use the prior global value that was in effect when their connections began.

---

Re your comment:

Note you have log-queries-not-using-indexes set. This means to log *all* queries that don't use indexes, even if the query was quicker than long_query_time.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html says:

> The server uses the controlling parameters in the following order to
>   determine whether to write a query to the slow query log:
>
> - The query must either not be an administrative statement, or
>     --log-slow-admin-statements must have been specified.
> - The query must have taken at least long_query_time seconds, or
>     log_queries_not_using_indexes must be enabled and the query used no
>     indexes for row lookups.
> - The query must have examined at least min_examined_row_limit rows.

Note that "not using indexes" is a little counter-intuitive. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes says:

> [The log-queries-not-using-indexes] option does not necessarily mean that no index is used. For example, a query that uses a full index scan uses an index but would be logged because the index would not limit the number of rows.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions! Mysql has been restarted multiple times since I've applied this change. I've also logged into mysql and verified the variable long_query_time is set to 10. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Many thanks! That sounds exactly what the problem is. I really appreciate you being able to find that information.